# node.js SIP implementation class structure

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, protocols, sip

I am trying to build a SIP implementation in Node.js. I would like to use this library to build out SIP UASs and UACs My entire implementation is at this GitHub repo my question relates to SIP dialogs and transactions. I am still building out the transaction logic but it will be similar to how I currently have dialogs working. My question is how the classes should be laid out. Currently, I have all SIP messages sent out using my Dialog class. But after doing some reading on RFC 3261 I noticed that a REGISTER request should not be classified as a Dialog. I would like to not have redundant logic everywhere so I was wondering if it would be better to have all of my logic for message matching (matching either to a transaction or dialog) be inside the message class. But this seems wrong to me. I can not find much information about SIP implementations in an object-oriented approach and was wondering if anyone here has any experience in this matter.

an example of making a simple SIP call with my library looks like this

```
var Client = new SIP(asteriskIP, asteriskPort, username, password);

Client.Register().then(dialog => {
    console.log("REGISTERED")
    call("69");
})

//receive a call
Client.on('INVITE', (res) => {
    console.log("Received INVITE")
    //create new Invite Message from the received message.
    console.log(res)
    var invite = Client.Message("INVITE", {branchId: res.branchId, callId: res.callId, cseq: res.cseq_count}).create();
    //create new dialog with the returned message.
    var call_dialog = Client.Dialog(invite.message).then(dialog => {
        dialog.on('401', (res) => {
            console.log('INVITE 401')
            var a = invite.Authorize(res); //generate authorized message from the original invite request
            dialog.send(a)
        })

        dialog.on('200', (res) => {
            console.log('INVITE 200')
        })

        dialog.on('INVITE', (res) => {
            //create all the parameters to keep send messages within the same dialog.
            var p = {
                extension: username,
                branchId: Parser.getBranch(res),
                callId: Parser.getCallId(res),
                cseq: Parser.getCseq(res),
                cseq_method: Parser.getResponseType(res),
            }

            console.log(res.CreateResponse(100))
        })

    })
})


//function to make a call
var call = (extension) => {
var media;
//var invite_request = Client.Message("INVITE", {extension:extension}).create();

var message = Client.Message({
    isResponse: false,
    protocol: "SIP/2.0",
    method: "INVITE",
    requestUri: `sip:${extension}@${asteriskDOMAIN}`,
    headers: {
        'Via': `SIP/2.0/UDP ${clientIP}:${clientPort};branch=${Builder.generateBranch()}`,
        'From': `<sip:${username}@${asteriskDOMAIN}>;tag=${Builder.generateBranch()}`,
        'To': `<sip:${extension}@${asteriskDOMAIN}>`,
        'Call-ID': `${Builder.generateBranch()}@${clientIP}`,
        'CSeq': `1 INVITE`,
        'Contact': `<sip:${username}@${clientIP}:${clientPort}>`,
        'Max-Forwards': '70',
        'User-Agent': 'Node.js SIP Library',
        'Content-Type': 'application/sdp',
        'Content-Length': '0'
    },
    body: ''
})

Client.Dialog(message).then(dialog => {
    
    
    dialog.on('401', (res) => {
        var a = message.Authorize(res); //generate authorized message from the original invite request
        console.log(`authorize message for ${extension}`)
        dialog.send(a)
    })

    dialog.on('200', (res) => {
        console.log(`200 OK ext: ${extension}`)
        console.log(res.ParseSDP())
        //media.start()
    })

    dialog.on('INVITE', (res) => {
        console.log(`INVITE from ${extension}`)
        console.log(res.ParseSDP())
        //media.start()
    })

    dialog.on('180', (res) => {
        console.log(`Ringing ${extension}`)
    })

    dialog.on('BYE', (res) => {
        console.log(`BYE from ${extension}`)
        var p = {
            extension: username,
            branchId: Parser.getBranch(res),
            callId: Parser.getCallId(res),
            cseq: Parser.getCseq(res),
        }
        var ok_response = Client.Message("200", p).create();
        dialog.send(ok_response.message);
    })
})
```

I love the idea of being able to listen for events on a certain dialog or maybe transactions. that way you could do all sorts of custom things with SIP. But I still want to be compliant with the RFC as far as terminology and implementation goes.

I would like to keep most things stateless and have only a few primitive classes that actually have a state such as the Dialog class Transaction class and Message class. but was thinking that maybe this would all have to be tracked in the Main sip class anyways so the rest could be stateless if that's the case.

What I really think my main issue is the difference between Dialogs, Transaction, and how sip messages interact with each "structure" There are all sorts of conflicting information around the internet and really just want some clear concise answers from someone who actually knows what they are talking about.

how should my classes interact?

currently creating a dialogue is the only method I have of sending any sip messages.

should I have logic just for transaction matching in the transaction class and then somehow emit the event to its Dialog? or can transactions also exist outside of a dialog?

or instead, should I just do all matching logic in the main SIP class and then dispatch it to either the Dialog or the Transaction? I'm very confused by all the conflicting information on the web and any help is GREATLY appreciated.